# Error while getting a file path using a dialog in PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I am using a dialog to get a filename path. I have managed to get it running and saving it to a local variable but Qt does not return the file path written in the pythonic way.

My cood is simple as that:

```
    u = str( QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName())
```

but it returns me something like this:

```
C:/Artur/PC/Trabalho Darlan/
```

instead

```
C:\Artur\PC\Trabalho Darlan\
```

I have tried to replace / for \ with no success. What should I do?

Comment: [os.path.normpath](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=abspath#os.path.normpath).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt returns all paths using / as the separator.

You can use the `abspath()` method:

```
os.path.abspath(u)
```

Or the toNativeSeparators method provided by Qt's QDir:

```
QDir.toNativeSeparators(u)
```